# Can't find missing VS Code 1.43 key bindings to replace cursor keys with h,j,k,l for the file explorer (most others included here)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to make sure wherever you can use a cursor key to move the selection/cursor you can also use alt + h/j/k/l. I have managed it in many places, but can't get it working for the file explorer. I want to move up and down using j/k. Here is what I have so far, is this optimal, and how to I add the file explorer?

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
  // use alt + h, j, k and l as cursors
  //
  // when in textInputFocus mode move cursor
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  // when in listFocus mode
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "list.focusDown",
    "when": "listFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "list.focusUp",
    "when": "listFocus"
  },
  // when in quick open mode
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
    "when": "!editorFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
    "when": "!editorFocus"
  },
  // when in suggestion mode
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  // when in smartSelect mode
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+h",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, I copy/pasted all cursor actions from latest definition and replaced with additional shortcut:

`keybindings.json`

```
[
  // textInputFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus"
  },
  // historyNavigation
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "history.showPrevious",
    "when": "historyNavigationEnabled && historyNavigationWidget"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "history.showNext",
    "when": "historyNavigationEnabled && historyNavigationWidget"
  },
  // listFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "list.focusUp",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "list.focusDown",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "list.expand",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "list.collapse",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  // explorerViewletCompressedFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "nextCompressedFolder",
    "when": "explorerViewletCompressedFocus && explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerViewletCompressedLastFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "previousCompressedFolder",
    "when": "explorerViewletCompressedFocus && explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerViewletCompressedFirstFocus && !inputFocus"
  },
  // notificationFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "notifications.focusPreviousToast",
    "when": "notificationFocus && notificationToastsVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "notifications.focusNextToast",
    "when": "notificationFocus && notificationToastsVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+l",
    "command": "notification.expand",
    "when": "notificationFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+h",
    "command": "notification.collapse",
    "when": "notificationFocus"
  },
  // suggestWidget
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
  },
  // editorFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "showPrevParameterHint",
    "when": "editorFocus && parameterHintsMultipleSignatures && parameterHintsVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "showNextParameterHint",
    "when": "editorFocus && parameterHintsMultipleSignatures && parameterHintsVisible"
  },
  // interactivePlaygroundFocus
  {
    "key": "alt+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.interactivePlayground.arrowUp",
    "when": "interactivePlaygroundFocus && !editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.interactivePlayground.arrowDown",
    "when": "interactivePlaygroundFocus && !editorTextFocus"
  },
  // smartSelect
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+h",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```